# Не работает регулярное выражение в QT

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает регулярное выражение, которое должно найти строки 'id="667236"'

```
QString test = "<article id=\"667236\" data-navigatable=\"\"<article id= \"667236\" data-navigatable=\"\"<article id=\"667236\" data-navigatable=\"\"";
    QRegExp reg("id=\"(\\d+)\"");
    if(reg.exactMatch(test))
    {
           QString id = reg.cap(1);
    }
```

Comment: А если так `reg(".*id=\"(\\d+)\".*");`

Comment: @KoVadim Вообще весь текст взял

Comment: В Id находится весь текст? Или только цифры? Да, эта регулярка матчит все, но скобки только цифры.

Comment: Используйте Raw string literal для строк: `R"any_prefix(<article id="667236"/>)any_prefix"`, их проще читать. И напишите, что именно у вас не работает. Предположу, что в строке несколько вариантов совпадений, и `QRegExp::exactMatch`  не рассчитана на это. Попробуйте перейти на `QRegularExpression`, у него есть функция `globalMatch`, возвращающая итератор.

Comment: @KoVadim если с группой, то да, но это тестовое выражение, так как в итоге это регулярное выражение должно парсить html страницу

Comment: @Ariox он возвращает просто пустую строку и не находит совпадений. Однако с QRegularExpression все заработало, почему?

Comment: ExactMatch пытается заматчить всю строку. То есть, можно считать, что оно неявно добавляет ^ и $ к выражению. Поэтому, когда я добавил .*, оно начало матчить

Answer (score 0):

У вас задвоенный слэш перед d. Правильное регулярное выражение:

```
id="(\d+)"
```

[Песочница](https://regex101.com/r/5puIUP/1).

Comment: В c++ \\-это литерал передающий \, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: У автора вопроса двойной слеш правильно указан.